# How to disable more than one NumericUpDown controls using one method?

Tags: c#, numericupdown

i have a form with more than one NumericUpDown as controls to input answer. i want every input is true for an operation (multiplication, sum etc), NumericUpDown for that operation will be disable. i have used the code below (just for sum operation), but i think its not efficient because i have to make a method to check every operation.

```
 private void IsSumTrue() {
        if (add1 + add2 == sum.Value)
        {
            sum.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void IsDifferenceTrue()
    {
        if (add1 - add2 == difference.Value)
        {
            difference.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void IsProductTrue()
    {
        if (add1 * add2 == product.Value)
        {
            product.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void IsQuotientTrue()
    {
        if (add1 / add2 == quotient.Value)
        {
            quotient.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

anyone have idea how to make it more efficient with just a method for all operation?

below is my idea, but to check the value is true for every NumericUpDown i don't know how.

```
private void DisableIfValueIsTrue()
    {
        foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            NumericUpDown value = control as NumericUpDown;
            // if(value [NEED HELP]

        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to disable every `NumericUpDown` if `add1 + add2 == sum.Value` ?

Comment: @AlexJolig just for numericupdown that for sum operation. the case is i have 8 numericupdown for 8 operations. so every numericupdown will disable if the answer for it's operation is true. one by one.

Comment: What is *its operation* ?

Comment: @AlexJolig: there are operation for sum, multiplication, square, difference, etc

Comment: as it stands, your questions doesn't make sense.. you don't have to make a method for each, you have to make a conditional block for each..

Comment: thanks for your attention, @BrettCaswell. but can you make it more detail. or just write something in the answer box.

Comment: @red, I'm saying your issue is semantics here.. 1 method can call 8 methods, 8 if else blocks, or 8 anonymous func delegates.. your issue is it still 'How to determine which control is associated to which operation, which correlates to which condition should I apply for this control instance'..

Comment: things would be a little different if you could add the controls to the form programmatically (not via form designer).. because then you could do a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Control,Func<bool>>>` using the control instance.. something of that nature.

Comment: @BrettCaswell check the update question. just add more code as explanation.

Comment: as @AlexJolig pointed out in his answer.. it becomes `quotient.Enabled = (add1 / add2 == quotient.Value)` .. this same operation/statement for each control instance.. in 1 method..

Comment: actually, you could still create your own `collection<object<NumericUpDown, Func<bool>>` at Form Init event, and add these controls and their conditions to them in that manner.. I'm not sure why that didn't occur to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your situtaion, you can set a tag for each `NumericUpDown` in design mode like this:

```
sum.Tag=1;
square.Tag=2;
etc
```

Then define some int variables:

```
int iSum=add1+add2;
int iSquare= //Whatever you want
etc
```

And finally loop through your controls this way:

```
foreach (NumericUpDown control in this.Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>())
{
  int intCondition = Convert.ToInt32(control.Tag) == 1
                      ? iSum
                      : Convert.ToInt32(control.Tag) == 2
                        ? iSquare
                        : Convert.ToInt32(control.Tag) == 3
                           ? i3
                           : i4; //You should extend this for your 8 controls
control.Enabled = intCondition == control.Value;
}
```

**OK! Second way I offer**

Since you will have to always check 8 different conditions, you could simply forget about looping through the controls and just change your method like this:

```
private void DisableIfValueIsTrue() 
{
  sum.Enabled = add1 + add2 != sum.Value;
  difference.Enabled= add1 - add2 != difference.Value;
  product.Enabled= add1 * add2 != product.Value;
  quotient.Enabled= (add2 !=0) && (add1 / add2 != quotient.Value);
  //etc
}
```

Comment: that is just for numericupdown's sum operation. the case is i have 8 numericupdowns for 8 operations. so every numericupdown will disable if the answer for it's operation is true. one by one.

Comment: @AlexJolig ,.. you should not be doing this in a foreach loop at all at this point..

Comment: @BrettCaswell Why is that?

Comment: don't get me wrong, declaring a value on the tag property so you programmatically identify which operation should apply to which control instance is helpful, but the control is already defined on his form.. you may as well just be comparing Object.Equals here

Comment: or better yet, not iterate in the first place

Comment: @AlexJolig check the update question. just add more code as explanation.

Comment: @red I think the second way I offered is the best way you can go by

Comment: @AlexJolig i've used the 2nd way, but when i run my program all of the numericupdown was disable before i enter an input.

Comment: @red My bad! Change `==` to `!=`. Updated my answer

Comment: also.. you're going to want to ensure `add2` is not 0

Comment: @BrettCaswell: thanks for advice. i've handle it like  intAdd2Random.Next(1, 25).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this while doing some research and would like to give my solution I used for my situation and hope it helps people. I needed minimum and maximum numbers for a calculation, so mine are named appropriately and I correlated these with some CheckBoxes. I used null in beginning of minimum and end of maximum to account for empty. I also had to create an event handler SubscribeToEvents() shown below.

In my load event for my form:

```
SubscribeToEvents();
_checkBoxs = new[] { cbXLight, cbLight, cbMedium, cbHeavy, cbXHeavy,     cbXXHeavy, cbXXXHeavy };
_minimumsNumericUpDowns = new[] { null, nLightMin, nMediumMin, nHeavyMin, nXHeavyMin, nXXHeavyMin, nXXXHeavyMin };
_maximumsNumericUpDowns = new[] { nXLightMax, nLightMax, nMediumMax, nHeavyMax, nXHeavyMax, nXXHeavyMax, null };
```

then I created a method:

```
private void DisableNumericUpDowns()
{
    // disable everything:
    foreach (var n in _minimumsNumericUpDowns)
    {
        if (n != null)
            n.Enabled = false;
    }
    foreach (var n in _maximumsNumericUpDowns)
    {
        if (n != null)
            n.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The event handler:

```
    private bool _eventsSubscribed;
    private void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        if (_eventsSubscribed)
            return;
        _eventsSubscribed = true;

        cbXXHeavy.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
        cbXHeavy.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
        cbXLight.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
        cbHeavy.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
        cbLight.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
        cbMedium.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
        cbXXXHeavy.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_NumericState;
    }
```

Now I can used this to check when they are enabled and if they are greater than or less than 0 if needed in the method CheckBox:

```
    private void CheckBox_NumericState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // disable everything
    DisableNumericUpDowns();

    // see if more than one checkbox is checked:
    var numChecked = _checkBoxs.Count((cb) => cb.Checked);

    // enable things if more than one item is checked:
    if (numChecked <= 1) return;

    // find the smallest and enable its max:
    var smallest = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < _checkBoxs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!_checkBoxs[i].Checked) continue;
        if (_maximumsNumericUpDowns[i] != null)
        {
            _maximumsNumericUpDowns[i].Enabled = true;
        }
        smallest = i;
        break;
    }

    // find the largest and enable its min:
    var largest = -1;
    for (var i = _checkBoxs.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!_checkBoxs[i].Checked) continue;
        if (_minimumsNumericUpDowns[i] != null)
        {
            _minimumsNumericUpDowns[i].Enabled = true;
        }
        largest = i;
        break;
    }

    // enable both for everything between smallest and largest:
    var tempVar = largest - 1;
    for (var i = (smallest + 1); i <= tempVar; i++)
    {
        if (!_checkBoxs[i].Checked) continue;
        if (_minimumsNumericUpDowns[i] != null)
        {
            _minimumsNumericUpDowns[i].Enabled = true;
        }
        if (_maximumsNumericUpDowns[i] != null)
        {
            _maximumsNumericUpDowns[i].Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    }
```

So I can check each state as required:

I want to check if Extra Light is check:

```
// Extra Light
if (!cbXLight.Checked) return;
if (nXLightMax.Enabled == false)
{
    _structCategoryType = XLight;
    CheckStructureSheets();
}
else
{
    if (nXLightMax.Value > 0)
    {
        _dMax = nXLightMax.Value;
        _structCategoryType = XLight;
        CheckStructureSheets();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Extra Light Max cannot be zero (0)");
    }
}
```

and next light checks both:

```
    // Light
    if (cbLight.Checked)
    {
        if (nLightMin.Enabled == false && nLightMax.Enabled == false)
        {
            _structCategoryType = Light;
            CheckStructureSheets();
        }
        else
        {
            if (nLightMin.Enabled && nLightMin.Value > 0)
            {
    if (nXLightMax.Enabled && nLightMin.Enabled && nLightMax.Enabled == false)
    {
        _dMin = nLightMin.Value;
        _structCategoryType = Light;
       CheckStructureSheets();
    }
    else
    {
        if (nLightMax.Value > 0)
       {
            _dMin = nLightMin.Value;
            _dMax = nLightMax.Value;
            _structCategoryType = Light;
            CheckStructureSheets();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Light Max cannot be zero (0)");
            return;
        }
}
        }
        else if (nLightMin.Enabled == false && nLightMax.Enabled)
        {
    if (nLightMax.Value > 0)
    {
    _dMax = nLightMax.Value;
    _structCategoryType = Light;
    CheckStructureSheets();
    }
    else
   {
    MessageBox.Show(@"Light Max cannot be zero (0)");
    }
            }
            else
            {
    MessageBox.Show(@"Light Min cannot be zero (0)");
    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.
Tim

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @AlexJoliq and @BrettCaswell. just want to inform that before Alex edited his answer from using "==" to "!=", i (thought) already solved the problem. but i don't know where is the more effective and efficient way, alex's or mine.

below is my code for `DisableIfValueIsTrue()`:

```
if (add1 + add2 == sum.Value) sum.Enabled = false;
if (add1 - add2 == difference.Value)  difference.Enabled = false;
if (add1 * add2 == product.Value) product.Enabled = false;
if (add1 / add2 == quotient.Value) quotient.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the optimizer would handle this, though I generally see the assignment operation of a Boolean expression (@AlexJoliq's) method to be more efficient.

Comment: also, your snippet here differs in that it will never re-enable the control state. I'm not sure whether that was a consideration...

Comment: @Bratt is right. if you use this mehotd, you have to produce more codes somewhere else to re-enable your controls. So I still think it's more efficient to do it the way I offered.